# Safari extension's content CSS priority issue

Tags: css, safari-extension

I found a problem with how Safari prioritises CSS between the css included with the HTML page and the injected content CSS. I created a [minimal reproducible](https://github.com/MikeSpock/safari-extension-css-bug) showcase and uploaded it to GitHub.

The issue is as follows: Extension-injected CSS is overruled by lower-hierarchy css rules from the website itself. In this screenshot `div{}` rule is within the website's CSS, and `div.hello{}` rule is declared in the Safari extension's content CSS and injected by Safari.

*Result:* 
The div in the HTML is red, instead of blue.The screenshot shows that Safari uses `div{}` with higher priority over `div.hello{}`. Please note, that `initial` rules are added by Safari automatically. The content CSS doesn't include such declaration.

[image]

Please see minimal example here, or the GitHub repo I created for a minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/MikeSpock/safari-extension-css-bug

**How to create stable CSS for the markup I add to websites via my Safari extension, seeing that every CSS within the website overrules the CSS from the extension?** This is not how Chrome extension work for example, it works as you might expect, handling CSS priorities correctly.

---

### Minimal viable example:

## `showcase.safari.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="./">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./showcase.safari.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    This should have a red background.
</div>
<div class="hello">
    This should have a green background.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## `showcase.safari.css`

```
div{
    background:red;
}
```

## `showcase.safariextension/content.css`

*This is the css injected via a Safari extension*

```
div.hello {
    background:green;
}
```

## `showcase.safariextension/Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Builder Version</key>
    <string>13607.1.40.1.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>safari-extension-css-bug</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.safari-extension-css-bug</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Content</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Stylesheets</key>
        <array>
            <string>content.css</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ExtensionInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>Permissions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Website Access</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Include Secure Pages</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Level</key>
            <string>All</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Add `showcase.safariextension` folder as a Safari Extension via Safari Extension Builder, and open `showcase.safari.html` for a minimal example.

Comment: Are you sure the style is actually being applied to the page? If you remove the div style, what happens?

Comment: Hey @Pete, as what I'd expect, it shows the second box in green.

Comment: Additionally, !important flag does get the extension CSS prioritized over the in-page CSS

Comment: Please add the [mcve] here in stackoverflow so that it will stay here with the question. External content may be removed or modified and for example I won't click external links here, nor should I.

Comment: @Esko, understood, sure, added a minimal example inline.

Comment: Safari's documentation says the following "Injected style sheets are treated as user style sheets, as defined by the W3C. This means that first your injected styles are defined, then the author’s styles are added, then any of the author’s properties declared as !important are added, then your properties defined as !important are added. At each stage, a new definition overrides any previous one." 
It still shouldn't mean that div.hello{} rule is to be overruled by div{}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that was good enough for me, and possibly a good general practice when developing extensions.

**Change all your html tags** you generate in your content script such as

- div
- a

and others **to custom tags**, so that it would never collide with the website's own style definitions:

- adiv
- aa

Then you can make sure you start your styles from scratch and nothing would be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this problem building Safari Extension.

I found 2 solutions:

1. Add `!important` to everything. Here is an example of a plugin that does this: [Polyglot](https://github.com/uetchy/Polyglot/blob/master/PolyglotSafariExtension/ContentScript/content.css)
2. Bundle the CSS with your .js file and inject it in a style tag inline after Dom is loaded (Safari will then treat your CSS the same as the site's own and obey the specificity order rules):

Using Webpack and ['style-loader' I configured](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#custom-elements-shadow-dom) my webpack.config.js:

```
const insertAtTop = (element) => {
  if (window.top === window) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {    
      var parent = document.querySelector("head");
      var lastInsertedElement =
        window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader;

      if (!lastInsertedElement) {
        parent.insertBefore(element, parent.firstChild);
      } else if (lastInsertedElement.nextSibling) {
        parent.insertBefore(element, lastInsertedElement.nextSibling);
      } else {
        parent.appendChild(element);
      }

      window._lastElementInsertedByStyleLoader = element;
    })
  }
};
```

...

```
module: {
  rules: [
    ....
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "style-loader",
          options: {
            insert: insertAtTop,
          },
        },
        "css-loader",
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your JS/ TSX / TS file import the CSS file:

```
import '../Resources/style.css';
```

Though this can be achieved in principle manually or without webpack.

NOTE: When using this method you DO NOT need to import via SFSafariStyleSheet key in `info.plist`, so remove it from there.